# Quantlib Calendar Advance

Tags: quantlib

Hi I'm trying to advance a business date (28-12-2012) by 1 day and 1 week according to the Japan calendar.

```
import QuantLib as ql

trade_date = ql.Date(28, 12, 2012)
calendar = ql.Japan()

calendar.advance(trade_date, ql.Period('1D'))
Out[23]: Date(4,1,2013)

calendar.advance(trade_date, ql.Period('1W'))
Out[24]: Date(4,1,2013)
```

Seems a bit strange advancing the trade date by one day or one week give the same result. Any ideas why this might be the case? The 1 day result looks right. But the 1 week result seems off.

Incidentally

```
calendar.advance(ql_trade_date, ql.Period('5D'))
Out[25]: Date(10,1,2013)
```

How is `calendar.advance(ql_trade_date, ql.Period('1W'))` to be interpreted? I was trying to compute the expiry of a 1 week option.

Comment: A more fundamental problem is, what is "Japan calendar"? E.g. looking at https://www.financialcalendar.com/wp-content/uploads/coverage/FinancialCalendar_Holidays.xls , I see **39** Japan calendars, including ISDA Standard TYO holidays, Tokyo bank holidays, and TONA (Tokyo Overnight Average) non-publication days. We really should stop using the poor architecture in QuantLib that assumes the existence of some kind of "country" or "currency" holiday.

Comment: QuantLib does have multiple calendars per country — see `UnitedStates` for instance.  The `Japan` class can be extended in the same way given a motivated contributor.

Comment: @Luigi Ballabio Agreed, the calendar classes can easily expanded similar to the US calendars.

Comment: Thanks. IMHO it would be better if `UnitedStates()` etc by itself did not work, but required the caller to be more specific. People get confused as to whether Good Friday, Columbus Day, etc are "U.S. holidays".

Comment: I see, so the constructor would force passing the specific market.  Good point.

Answer (score 1):

A decent calendar library should go beyond ql.Japan().isBusinessDay(d) and be able to explain *why* a day is not a business day.

December 28, 2012 is a Friday, a working day.

December 29, 2012 is a Saturday, not a working day.

December 30, 2012 is a Sunday, not a working day.

December 31, 2012 is a December 31 bank holiday https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/japan/december-31-bank-holiday

January 1, 2013 is New year's day

January 2, 2013 is January 2 bank holiday https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/japan/january-2-bank-holiday

January 3, 2013 is January 3 bank holiday https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/japan/january-3-bank-holiday

January 4, 2013 is Friday, the next working day after December 28, 2012.

You may find these comments in the code helpful: https://rkapl123.github.io/QLAnnotatedSource/dc/d44/class_quant_lib_1_1_japan.html

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri Vulis. Have you got any other libraries you would recommend? I'm aware of the holiday list, but that doesn't answer the question why the 2 calls above give the same result. I would have expected the 1w call to advance by 5 business days.

Comment: The 1w call advances by one week, so from Dec 28th to Jan 4th, and then possibly adjusts to the next business day (not in this case, as Jan 4th is a business day already). In short, weeks work like months or years.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense

Comment: I once added a call to the firm's internal (sorry) library  that took a calendar (like "NYK&London" because term sheets often use a union of 2 or 3 calendars), start date, and end date, and returns a structure listing the dates and clearly explaining why (e.g. New Years day (Observed) in NYK and London).

Comment: @DimitriVulis Agree this would be a useful feature in QuantLib

Comment: @mark I used to work in an environment with multiple analytics libraries. Some were internal and generally shared good infrastructure (and also if we didn't like something, we could change it). However, one incorporated all of (an old version of) ql and was no fun at all. I grew to dislike certain ql design decisions because of having to deal with them.

Comment: By the way, C++ quantlib calendar has holidayList(), which returns a list of dates, But it doesn't explain _why_ these dates are holidays. Also it's not exposed in Python (but that's easy to add).